# How to solved "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am making my first registration form in **ASP.NET** and also using some **Javascript** I am presenting the following error when registering

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

The following is my javascript code:

```
function f_submitForm() {
    $("#submit").css("display", "none");
    $("#load").css("display", "block");


    const auxPriorityInput = document.getElementById("ticketPriorityInput");
    const auxticketService = document.getElementById("ticketServiceInput");
    const auxticketSubService = document.getElementById("ticketSubServiceInput");
    const auxCategoryInput = document.getElementById("ticketCategoryInput");
    const auxticketOrigin = document.getElementById("ticketOriginInput");

    const form = new FormData();

    const ins = document.getElementById("file").files.length;
    for (let x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
        form.append("files[]", document.getElementById("file").files[x]);
    }

    form.append("ticketIdAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketIdAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketNameAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketNameAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketEmailAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketEmailAppliInput").value);    
    form.append("ticketExtAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketExtAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketPhoneAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketPhoneAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketAreaAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketAreaAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketLocationAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketLocationAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketSubjectInput", document.getElementById("ticketSubjectInput").value);
    form.append("ticketDescrInput", document.getElementById("ticketDescrInput").value);
    form.append("ticketPriorityInput", auxPriorityInput.options[auxPriorityInput.selectedIndex].value);
    form.append("ticketServiceInput", auxticketService.options[auxticketService.selectedIndex].value);
    form.append("ticketSubServiceInput", auxticketSubService.options[auxticketSubService.selectedIndex].value);
    form.append("ticketCategoryInput", auxCategoryInput.options[auxCategoryInput.selectedIndex].value);
    form.append("ticketOriginInput", auxticketOrigin.options[auxticketOrigin.selectedIndex].value);
```

Looking in the console of my browser I find the error

[Console image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAAV9.png)

Exactly in the property of `ticketExtAppliInput` possibly the error is due to the fact that I need to make a validation with this field when this void was sent to save 0 by default, but I am not sure how to do it, if that can be the solution you can tell me how fix it if not what would be the correct solution

**UPDATE:**

I have two forms but depending on the session variables certain fields are loaded, `ticketExtAppliInput` has to go in both one and the other, the difference is that in which I need also goes `ticketExtAppliInput` but it is not being entered I need it to be stored by default the "0" value

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-body">
                        <div class="mb-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketExtAppliInput">Extensión:</label>
                                    <input step="1" id="ticketExtAppliInput" type="number" maxlength="6" oninput="if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" name="extension" class="form-control form-control-user">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You can't get a `value` property of a function's params.  Here's a quick list of what you can get the value from.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going around and around I found the solution to my validation problem and managed to do it as follows, try to make a validation in case this is empty assign the value 0

```
function f_submitForm() {
$("#submit").css("display", "none");
$("#load").css("display", "block");

const auxPriorityInput = document.getElementById("ticketPriorityInput");
const auxticketService = document.getElementById("ticketServiceInput");
const auxticketSubService = document.getElementById("ticketSubServiceInput");
const auxCategoryInput = document.getElementById("ticketCategoryInput");
const auxticketOrigin = document.getElementById("ticketOriginInput");


const form = new FormData();

const ins = document.getElementById("file").files.length;
for (let x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
    form.append("files[]", document.getElementById("file").files[x]);
}

form.append("ticketIdAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketIdAppliInput").value);
form.append("ticketNameAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketNameAppliInput").value);
form.append("ticketEmailAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketEmailAppliInput").value);    
if ($('ticketExtAppliInput').val() == "") {

    //we give it the value of zero by not having any value
    document.getElementById("ticketExtAppliInput").value = "0";
} 
form.append("ticketPhoneAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketPhoneAppliInput").value);
form.append("ticketAreaAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketAreaAppliInput").value);
form.append("ticketLocationAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketLocationAppliInput").value);
form.append("ticketSubjectInput", document.getElementById("ticketSubjectInput").value);
form.append("ticketDescrInput", document.getElementById("ticketDescrInput").value);
form.append("ticketPriorityInput", auxPriorityInput.options[auxPriorityInput.selectedIndex].value);
form.append("ticketServiceInput", auxticketService.options[auxticketService.selectedIndex].value);
form.append("ticketSubServiceInput", auxticketSubService.options[auxticketSubService.selectedIndex].value);
form.append("ticketCategoryInput", auxCategoryInput.options[auxCategoryInput.selectedIndex].value);
form.append("ticketOriginInput", auxticketOrigin.options[auxticketOrigin.selectedIndex].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please post your HTML.  It is hard to tell what is going on without it.

But the error is pretty straight-forward. It looks like you have no element with `id="ticketExtAppliInput"` in your HTML.  Check for misspellings or why it is otherwise missing. This is the most likely cause of `getElementById` returning `null`.

Comment: check the HTML element  `"ticketExtAppliInput"` exists

Comment: Check your browser dev tools at runtime.  Is it possible that this element was removed, hidden or renamed prior to the call?  The browser is saying it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests that javascript could not find the element with id "ticketExtAppliInput". First course of action would be to check your HTML and ensure that the id on that element is spelled correctly.

The more general problem is that you're searching for elements in the DOM, and then trying to access their "value" property. Best practice would be to ensure that you are actually finding this element before assuming you can get its value.